# trigger a DNS change in Active directory

Tags: monitoring

Can I get solar winds to change a DNS alias in Active directory based upon a specific set of events or conditions?
I have a collection of applications that use hostnames in combination with database names in order to resolve database connections, problem is that they haven't considered how a failover would work in practice so I want the product to provoke a change in DNS to point the apps at the right place if we get into a failure situation.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows includes the `dnscmd` command that can edit records from a command-line.  Take a look at the `/NodeDelete` and `/RecordAdd` commands. If you write a bit of script and tie it to SolarWinds, you should be able to accomplish this.

If you rather use Powershell than windows script, I found this module on TechNet that could help:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Update-DNS-records-with-da10910d